# One sku may have few rows with different partner_id. How to SELECT skus which have just one record?

Tags: postgresql

I have such `partner_stockrecord` table:

```
"id"|"partner_sku"|"partner_id"
1      sku1          1
2      sku1          2

3      sku2          1
4      sku2          2
5      sku2          3

6      sku3          1

7      sku4          1
```

How can I `SELECT` just `sku` which does not have `partner_id=1 AND partner_id=2`, i.e how to `SELECT` just `sku3` and `sku4` in this case?

P.S. I am sure this is a duplication, but I cannot formulate a right search query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select partner_sku from partner_stockrecord as x
where not exists (
  select 1 from partner_stockrecord as y
  where x.partner_sku = y.partner_sku and y.partner_id = 1)
union
select partner_sku from partner_stockrecord as x
where not exists (
  select 1 from partner_stockrecord as y
  where x.partner_sku = y.partner_sku and y.partner_id = 2);
```

or

```
select partner_sku from partner_stockrecord
group by partner_sku
having not array_agg(partner_id) @> array[1,2];
```

or

```
select partner_sku from partner_stockrecord
group by partner_sku
having count(distinct partner_id) filter (where partner_id in (1,2)) < 2;
```

Just use one which is more efficient on your data.